# add subscriber to Single observed value

Tags: java, java-8, observable, rx-java2

I would like to know how can I add the subscriber for single as shown below in the code.
when i try to add .subscribe() or .blockingsubscribe() the autocomplete in eclise does not show them

**code**:

```
Single<List<List<Person>>> singles = Single.just(Main.getPersons());
    singles
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(x->System.out.println(x.size()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your map function should return something that you want to subscribe on:

```
.map(x -> {
    System.out.println(x.size());
    return ???;
 });
```

Comment: you still going to need a subscription

Comment: yes i know but can show me how to use the subscription?? i cant use it please provide an examlple

Comment: Single<List<List<Person>>> singles = Single.just(Main.getPersons());
    singles
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(x -> s.size())
    .subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x))

Comment: Could be the OP wants to print and return the size like you suggested. It is really hard to guess as the OP keeps asking questions with the very same code example over and over...

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong lambda and it throws off your IDE. Try this:

```java
Single<List<List<Person>>> singles = Single.just(Main.getPersons());
singles
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.doOnSuccess(x -> System.out.println(x.size()))
.  // <---------------------------------------- now it should bring up the autocomplete
```

Comment: You're right, he probably wants to use the .doOnNext

Comment: thanks but why i could not use .map directly? it is Single and i should use map operator normally??

Comment: also there is no doOnNext with songle

Comment: Map requires a `Function` that takes an item and returns an item. A lambda of `x -> System.out.println(x.size())` does not return anything as `println` is a `void` method. This is a syntax error so the IDE can no longer follow the types and suggest anything via autoComplete.